# Python pandas read CSV from sibling directory

Tags: python, pandas, directory

```
+-- parent_dir
|   +-- dir1
|       +-- script.py 
|   +-- dir2
|       +-- mycsv.csv
```

How can we read `mycsv.csv` from within the `script.py` script. We've tried `pd.read_csv("../dir2/mycsv.csv")` and received the error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`.

Comment: what's your working directory?

Comment: good question - locally it is `dir1` but in production it will likely be some home folder

Comment: Feeling dumb but the import above **actually does work** when we fix the TYPO in our string, when the working directory is **dir1**. However, this won't work on production where dir1 isn't the working directory, so still glad we asked!

Answer (score 4):

presumably you are not actually running it from inside dir1 (even though you think you are)

however you can do

```
 file_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
 csv_path = os.path.join(file_dir,"..","dir2","mycsv.csv")
```

and then it should work no matter where you run it from

as an aside you can try

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

to see  where you are actually executing it from

Comment: I thought only PHP had `__FILE__`! (Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

This depends more on the place you're trying to run `script.py` from.

For example, if you are in `parent_dir` and you do `python dir1/script.py`, then you would refer `mycsv.csv` as `dir2/mycsv.csv`.

So, you would either need to specify the full path e.g. `/home/user/parent_dir/dir2/mycsv.csv`.

If the location is always relative to `script.py` as you mentioned; you would do as indicated in the answer above.